# Somebody help me with these parameters which are about intel 5300 wifi card data , and what does that means?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wifi, intel

I forked a github project:https://github.com/OlympusKnight/CSIworks
and I don't know some parameters means.I know csi/rssi, but I don't know what is "agc", someone can tell me, thank you!

I can found some of them by google, e.g.'what is agc"

```
csi_struct = {"timestamp_low": timestamp_low, "bfee_count": 0, "Nrx": nrx, "Ntx": ntx, "rssi_a": rssi_a,
                      "rssi_b": rssi_b, "rssi_c": rssi_c, "noise": noise, "agc": agc, "perm": perm,
                      "rate": fake_rate_n_flags, "csi": csi}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [Automatic Gain Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_gain_control) which basically compensates the incoming signal amplitude attenuation to the transmitted power level. You can find more info in https://dhalperi.github.io/linux-80211n-csitool/faq.html